# How can I add multiple consumer group?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to add multiple kafka consumer group in my spring project. How can I add multiple consumer group?
My listener is such as below,

```
@KafkaListener(
        topics = {"#{'${test.topics}'.split(',')}"},
        groupId = "${test.kafka.consumer.groupid}",
        concurrency = "${test.concurrency}",
        containerFactory = "ListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    void messageReceiver(@Payload List<String> data) {
       
        System.out.println("Message read start:");
     
}
```

Comment: You can not add multiple consumer group for single consumer. You can add multiple consumers to single consumer group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like any other kafka client, define another consumer (`@KafkaListener`, here) with a unique `groupId`